# MS Access SQL statement for append

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm relatively new to MS Access and SQL.

I have a query in an access db to append one table to another, ordered ascending by a particular column, which I then use to add column for the purposes of assigning a unique identifier.

The query itself runs fine in access, however, I would like to write this into the VBA code of a form to action when a button is clicked.

The SQL view in access gives me the following code, but when I write it into my code it's stating that an operator is missing, can anybody make a suggestion?

Code:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tblImport ( CustomerAccount, OrderReference, OrderDate, DueDate, CustomerRef," & _
    "StockNo, OrderQuantity, AddressName, Add1, Add2, Add3, Town, County, PostCode, Country, ServiceLine )" & _
    "SELECT tblImport2.CustomerAccount, tblImport2.OrderReference, tblImport2.OrderDate, tblImport2.DueDate," & _
    "tblImport2.CustomerRef, tblImport2.StockNo, tblImport2.OrderQuantity, tblImport2.AddressName, tblImport2.Add1," & _
    "tblImport2.Add2, tblImport2.Add3, tblImport2.Town, tblImport2.County, tblImport2.PostCode, tblImport2.Country," & _
    "tblImport2.ServiceLine" & _
    "FROM tblImport2" & _
    "ORDER BY tblImport2.OrderReference")
```

Comment: Can you show us the `vba` code you have that is giving the error?  The `SQL` shown looks fine but perhaps there is an error in how you've transposed it into `VBA`

Comment: It's a bit too long :)

Comment: Based on your syntax error, I've had a shot at a quick guess, but even if you just post the `vba` statement that sets your `SQL` it should be enough to determine the problem (assuming my guess wasn't correct anyway)

Comment: See final comment on my answer for the reason you're having this trouble...

Comment: Thanks, Really appreciate your help.  All sorted

Answer (score 1):

Save the query. Then you can call it from code:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("NameOfYourAppendQuery").Execute
```

Or without the query:

```
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "<Your SQL string>"
Debug.Print Sql     ' Check SQL.
CurrentDb.Execute Sql
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I know how to run the query from the form code, I was just hoping to actually write the query into the code.  I have a few things going on with this form so I wanted to keep the number of queries in the db down to a minimum so that I don't lose track of what i'm linking to what.

Comment: Oh. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I tried that and it's failing in the same way my original code was. Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tblImport2.ServiceLine From tblImport2 Order by tblimport2.orderReference'.  looks like i'm missing a comma or semicolon or something but i'm not so clued up to figure out where

Comment: If your original query works, so will it if run from code. So probably you miss something. Check the SQL before executing - see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that in `VBA` to specify a multiline string (as your query is here), you need to join the lines together like this?  Otherwise `VBA` won't know it's supposed to be a single string.

```
mySql = "INSERT INTO tblImport ( CustomerAccount, OrderReference, OrderDate, DueDate, CustomerRef, StockNo, OrderQuantity, AddressName, Add1, Add2, Add3, Town, County, PostCode, Country, ServiceLine ) " & _
"SELECT tblImport2.CustomerAccount, tblImport2.OrderReference, tblImport2.OrderDate, tblImport2.DueDate, tblImport2.CustomerRef, tblImport2.StockNo, tblImport2.OrderQuantity, tblImport2.AddressName, tblImport2.Add1, tblImport2.Add2, tblImport2.Add3, tblImport2.Town, tblImport2.County, tblImport2.PostCode, tblImport2.Country, " & _
"tblImport2.ServiceLine " & _
"FROM tblImport2 " & _
"ORDER BY tblImport2.OrderReference; "
```

Comment: That's correct Dave, The code i originally put in was DoCmd.RunSQL etc etc.  All lines end " & _ and following lines start ".  When i run the query in access is executes perfectly.  No way of adding an attachment on here is there?

Comment: No, but you could just copy and paste the statement itself into an edit of the question.  Syntax errors mean something's not right with the statement, so seeing the statement is necessary to help resolve it

Comment: perfect.  Tried popping it in here but was too long by 200 odd characters :)

Comment: The error is that you need a space at the end of each line of the string.  Look at my answer above and compare it to yours.  You are effectively saying `"tblImport2.ServiceLineFROM tblImport2ORDER BY tblImport2.OrderReference"` unless you include the space required for the string to make sense

Comment: Superstar Dave.  All sorted.  I am pretty new to all this but was confident I wasn't far off.